# Receiving "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" in formControlName property

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 7 and Google Material Design, and I followed this tutorial for Reactive forms: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-formgroup-instance.

I have used a `formGroup`, along with `formControlName`. Here is my **login.component.ts** file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl(''),
    password: new FormControl(''),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() : void {
    console.log(this.loginForm.value);
  }
}
```

Here is my **login.component.html**:

```
<mat-card class="login-card">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
        <form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="login-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <table class="login-full-width" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="login-full-width">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <p>
                    Value: {{email.value}}
                </p>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="login-full-width">
                            <input matInput formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <mat-spinner [style.display]="showSpinner ? 'block' : 'none'"></mat-spinner>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" color="primary">Login</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

This is the error I get when navigating to the login page:

> LoginComponent.html:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (LoginComponent.html:15)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:23937)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23312)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23511)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23308)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:23548)

This is line 11 of **login.component.html**:

```
<input matInput type="text" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" required>
```

I followed the tutorial step by step, and it was very simple to follow. Did I miss something here that is causing the error?

Comment: This is the line that's causing the issue `<p>
                    Value: {{email.value}}
                </p>` is undefined

Comment: The template may be rendered before the class is initialized, so you need to test the value.  In templates, you should be able to use either `{{ email?.value }}` or `{{ email && email.value }}` depending on your stack.

Comment: where is `email` supposed to be defined? thats definitely not the same template as the one in the tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no email property in your class. You have to access the form value through the form group, like so:

```
<p>
 Value: {{loginForm.get('email').value}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a variable that you haven't defined in your LoginComponent class. If you only want to map the value of your input for debugging purposes you can use template variables. You simply add one in your input tag as follow: #email

[Check this official Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be:

```
 <input  type="text"  [formControl]="loginForm.controls.email" placeholder="Email" required>
```

{{loginForm.controls.email.value}}